# Best way to hide a button with .visible-desktop class?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, show-hide

I'm trying to hide a button using jQuery ( using `$.fn.hide()`) ,but the jQuery method does not work, because the elements I want to hide contains the Bootstrap `.visible-desktop`/`.hidden-desktop` class (using any Bootstrap's responsive class, really). It happens due to `.visible-desktop` is using the `display` attribute with `!important`. I want to display a button version for mobile/tablet different than desktop version *but I would want* to use my two buttons as a unique identity. A simpler version of my issue would be:

in HTML file:

```
<button class="my-button my-button-for-tablet-mobile hidden-desktop"></button>
<button class="my-button my-button-for-desktop visible-desktop"></button>
```

in jQuery file (Desired, but it does not work):

```
//A line of this type should hide the two buttons.
$(".my-button").hide();
```

I don't know what is the better way to implement this...

EDIT:

There is a JsFiddle about this question:

http://jsfiddle.net/bDLnN/

Comment: why not remove the class using http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ ?

Comment: `$('.my-button').attr('style', 'display: none !important');` will replace all style attributes. You must append. See this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668192/1873446)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to just use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to override it.

The following should work:

```
$('.my-button').attr('style', 'display: none !important')
```

Comment: @fcortes Really? It says in the specification here it should work - http://api.jquery.com/show/. Your css is not inline is it? Post me a jsFiddle so I can fix it?

Comment: @fcortes Try  `$('.my-button').attr('style', 'display: none !important');`

Comment: I've just created a JsFiddle.

Comment: Did you try my attr comment? I can check in ten mins just on phone (lunch break) atm :)

Comment: Yep, your piece of code finally works! Thanks! Modify your answer with the correct code and I will check it :p

Comment: @fcortes Sorry, just got back from lunch. Glad it works :D updated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object.setProperty (propertyName, propertyValue, priority);` function that receives a priority argument.

```
$(".my-button").each(function () {
    this.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
});
```

**[Reference](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdpsdnb.php)**

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in a mobile resolution, exactly the same that the code `$('.my-button').attr('style', 'display: none !important');`.

Comment: @fcortes `$('.my-button').attr('style', 'display: none !important');` will replace all style attributes. You must append. See this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668192/1873446](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668192/1873446)